# Looking to export the content from a website into doc files

Tags: formatting, export, expressionengine, doc

We currently have an website that we're rebuilding and we're looking to export all content into doc files so we're able to edit them. The current website is done in Expression Engine so we're open to plug ins that might help.

Comment: Hi, please try to give us more informations and what you tried until now.

Comment: I've managed to use HTTrack Website Copier to get everything into HTML but the issue with that is that it leaves 80k files which leaves us a a point where we might as well copy and paste for the amount of time it would take to go through everything.

I've also looked into plugins but can't seem to find anything that does quite what we're looking for,

Comment: I'd recommend you do the edits either in EE or in the new CMS.  I'd also recommend that you do the migration more directly by mapping the EE tables + columns to the database structure of the new CMS.  What is your target CMS?  There may already exist tutorials to guide you.